# Prolog rule is `true` and not return it as an argument

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment to collage to build a relation `sub(Sublist, List)` for all `Sublist`s of `List` such that the order of the members in `Sublist` is in the same order of the members as in `List`. For example:

```
?- sub(X, [1,2,3]).
```

satisfied by

```
X=[1,2,3];
X=[1,2];
X=[1,3];
X=[1];
X=[2,3];
X=[2];
X=[3];
X=[].
```

I've built this relation, and when I query `?- sub(X, [1,2,3]).` I get as a response only these `X` which are the prefix sublists of `List`:

```
X=[];
X=[1];
X=[1,2];
X=[1,2,3].
```

**But** when I query `?- sub([2], [1,2,3]).` or any other subset of `[1,2,3]` as the `Subset` argument I get `true` as an answer. How could this happen? Doesn't Prolog suppose to return **all** the `Subset`s that satisfy this relation?

I can't post the code because I would fail the assignment if someone from my class will copy the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the terms in one of the rules was `X\=Y` for 2 parameters `X` and `Y`.I deleted this check, and instead added a parameter in this recursive rule which is `1` if `X`=`Y` and `0` elsewise. I don't know why, maybe Prolog isn't enthusiastic to check primitive relations in rulse (such as `\=`), but that solved the problem.

Comment: try using `dif(X,Y)` instead of `X \= Y`.

Comment: @WillNess What is your recommended replacement for `X=Y`?

Comment: X=Y needs no replacement. = is unification. it is pure, logical. it is the heart of what Prolog is. Negation on the other hand is non-logical, non-pure, operational; results will differ depending on whether X and Y are instantiated or not. dif(X,Y) is like \=, but pure and logical, because it delays the checking until X and Y do become instantiated. it is thus more like taking a notice for the future: "we intend the values held by X and Y to be different". but plain X\=Y with "free" X and Y just fails.

Comment: ... just fails, because `\=` actually means "can not be unified at this point in time".